# How to use RunLoop in a Command Line Tool to use Combine Timer.pubish(...)?

Tags: swift, xcode

The solution to user Timer.publish() in a Command Line Tool app could be to use RunLoop. But I can figure out how.

If I write the following it doesn't work more than if I don't use RunLoop.

```
RunLoop.current.run()

let subscription = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
        print("timer fired")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by Ole Begemann on swift forums. Thx to him.

```
import Combine
import Foundation

let subscription = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
  .autoconnect()
  .sink { _ in
      print("timer fired")
  }

withExtendedLifetime(subscription) {
  RunLoop.current.run()
}
```

It seams "withExtendedLifetime(x:,body:)" is needed to avoid compiler to destroy the subscription instance before the RunLoop start.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is merely that you are giving the commands in the wrong order. Try it like this:

```
let subscription = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
        print("timer fired")
    }
RunLoop.current.run()
```

Comment: Actually it was not the way I tested it.

Comment: But the way you show didn't work. I had to include the RunLoop in the withExtendedLifetime block to make it working.

Comment: The code I quoted does repeatedly call the timer block on my machine. Sorry if it doesn’t do the same thing on your machine.

Comment: Do you execute it in a project based on Command Line tool template?

Comment: Yes, I did. As I say, I can't explain why it worked for me and not for you.

Comment: Read my discussion with Ole: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-combine-timer-pubish-in-command-line-tool/41345

Comment: I don't know what else you want me to say. The code I provided is the entirety of my code (except of course to import Foundation and Combine) and it prints `"timer fired"` repeatedly on my machine both in a Debug build and in a Release build. However, it is also true that this is not "normal" Combine code, because the subscriber is not being retained (there is no `.store` operator). In other words, if you showed only that code in a _normal_ app, I would not expect the timer to print anything.

Comment: ??!? I tried your code in a normal app, it works! Even without the RunLoop.